# Timestamp required in xdebug trace file

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I have configured xdebug in my application and I am getting below data in trace log.

I want to know the data at which time particular function was called. Or I need the time-stamp field in each row.

I have searched regarding this on google but no luck.

Can someone have any Idea weather it is possible using xdebug or not?

[image]

Comment: What do you try to achieve with that? XDebug provides debug information about PHP execution and the time since execution start provides enough debugging info.

Comment: I want to check at what time perticular function started excutiong. eg: at what time ini_set() was called and how much time it took. As per current screenshot I can se it took 0.0101 seconds(If I am not wrong) but at what time it started executing that I want to know.

Comment: As I understand, the first column represents the time since the program was started and that time is set in the first string. So there is no problem to get a sequence of function calls and their call time.

Comment: I guess second column is execution time. Should I add this time to program start time?

Comment: I think so. I think, it is time since program started because it constantly grows with a small amount of time so it is unlikely to be execution time.

Comment: yes you are correct